# sessionStorage proxy class scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class, sessionstorage, es6-proxy

I am wondering how to access the native sessionStorage scope from within my custom methods.

My example:

https://jsfiddle.net/3mc7ao7j/1/

At line 3 I would like to be able to proxy through to my native `sessionStorage` after perform my mutation on the data.

How do I access that scope again though? I know I can just call:

`sessionStorage.setItem()`

But that simply works because it is globally available and it feels wrong to do that. Mainly because I would also want to know how to do this without an object that is not globally available so I can learn how to proxy other objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some `window` objects like `location` are read-only, it can be useful to create abstractions over them or make use of DI for testability.

`sessionStorage` is supposed to be used as is. Usually no abstractions over it are needed. If its functionality should be extended or modified, a custom class can be created. It can implement [Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage#Properties) interface or have its own.

The use of `Proxy` is unjustified here. It is slow and restricts the code from being used in ES5 environments.

Custom class or object can just wrap original `sessionStorage` methods. Since Storage API is small, wrapper class results in ~20 lines of code:

```
class CustomSessionStorage {
  get length() {
    return sessionStorage.length;
  }

  getItem(key) {
    return sessionStorage.getItem(key);
  }
  ...
}
```

`sessionStorage` object is exotic. Although it inherits from `Storage`, `Storage` is not a constructor, and `sessionStorage` methods should be bound to `sessionStorage` directly, so it's not possible to make it work just with `CustomSessionStorage.prototype = sessionStorage`. Additionally, `sessionStorage` has `length` property descriptor that should be bound as well.

A more general way to extend it is to provide a base class that wraps original methods and can be extended further:

```
function BaseSessionStorage() {}

for (let prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Storage.prototype)) {
  if (typeof sessionStorage[prop] === 'function') {
    // bind all sessionStorage methods
    BaseSessionStorage.prototype[prop] = sessionStorage[prop].bind(sessionStorage);
  } else {
     // a proxy for other props, length is read-only getter
     Object.defineProperty(BaseSessionStorage.prototype, prop, {
       get: () => sessionStorage[prop],
       set: val => { sessionStorage[prop] = val }
     });
  }
}

class CustomSessionStorage extends BaseSessionStorage {
  getItem(key) {
    return super.getItem(key);
  }
  // the rest of API is inherited
}
```

Comment: I need a proxy if I want to implement custom methods for a native object but do not want to implement all of them. There is no other way. If I want to `JSON.stringify` data whenever I set something and `JSON.parse` it get I get an item 90% of the time I am not going to do this everytime. I simply want my proxylayer to take care of this.

Comment: I don't see a real need for Proxy here. This can be handled by a regular class (or probably object, since a storage is supposed to be a singleton). Regarding the original question, *How do I access that scope again though?*, you need to refer it as `sessionStorage.setItem()` explicitly inside `setItem`. You can use `this` in proxy methods, but only if a method is called differently: `set(k, v) { this.setItem(a, msg) }`.

Comment: If you simply wrap the original you have to also implement all methods if you want it to behave like the native `sessionStorage` object.

Comment: Yes. It's not that hard, that's the way it's usually done in custom storages, As you can see, there are only 5 methods and `length` prop. `Storage` is quite special and limits the ways it can be extended. And Proxy doesn't make it any easier if you want to extend original methods.

Comment: The implementation of all methods is the exact thing I want to prevent though . That is why I stated `so I can learn how to proxy other objects` at the end of the post. This is not just about this particular use case but also others. If I were to implement this for Google Maps I wouldn't want to have to implement all 50 methods just because I need to modify 4.

Comment: The question is about `sessionStorage`. It is exotic and requires special treatment. You shouldn't avoid it because that's how it should be done here. Even if you create a bogus class to extend, `class BaseSS {}; BaseSS.prototype = /* all Storage methods that are bound to sessionStorage */`, you still need to take care of `length`. For non-exotic objects the inheritance is usually plain and simple. Again, no `Proxy` is needed, everything is naturally handled by JS inheritance.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the recipe I meant. It will work for both exotic and regular objects (although less hacky inheritance methods are more preferable for regular objects).

Comment: Thanks I will try it out.

Comment: For the record, the issue regarding `JSON.stringify()` can be resolved by implementing a `toJSON()` member method on the custom class.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That's true. I guess the OP tries to make a convenience wrapper for the storage, so it could automatically serialize and deserialize objects.