# Extending `this` in Typescript class by Object.assign

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an object `remote` which is not a class instance itself. Due to the nature of Angular 2-5 I need to wrap this Object in a service so I can inject it into components. The object has an interface declared '`Remote`'.

How would I make the following work?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { remote, Remote } from 'electron';

@Injectable()
export class RemoteService implements Remote {
    constructor() {
        Object.assign(this, remote);
    }
}
```

I.e., how do I make a service class `RemoteService` which instances look like `Remote`, without having to manually wrap all `remote`'s members? I cannot use extend because `remote` is not itself an instance of a class, just an object.

In the example above the Typescript compiler will complain that `RemoteService` incorrectly implements `Remote` (naturally). Is there any way to coerce the compiler into understand `RemoteService` as implementing `Remote`?

Comment: Did you fully implement all the methods / properties of `Remote`?

Comment: Well, the thing is that `remote` implements those, but that to use DI in angular 2+ I need `remote` to be wrapped in a class. So what I want is a class that exports the `Remote` interface, but I don't want to have to wrap every single method in a public method on the class. Hence the `Object.assign(this, remote)`, which should copy all `remote` references to `this`. However, typescript complains that `RemoteService` doesn't implement `Remote`. Which I understand. But how to circumvent it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TypeScript class should be augmented with an interface. This results in merged declaration that asserts that `Remote` methods are implemented:

```
import { remote, Remote } from 'electron';

export interface RemoteService extends Remote {}

@Injectable()
export class RemoteService implements Remote {
    constructor() {
        Object.assign(this, remote);
    }
}
```

`Object.assign` will only work properly if properties are constant, and methods are own and enumerable.

For more efficient inheritance, base class can be created in order to provide prototype chain:

```
import { remote, Remote } from 'electron';

export interface BaseRemote extends Remote {}
export class BaseRemote implements Remote {}
Object.setPrototypeOf(BaseRemote.prototype, remote);
// or
/*
export const BaseRemote = function BaseRemote() {} as Function as { new(): Remote };
BaseRemote.prototype = remote;
*/

@Injectable()
export class RemoteService extends BaseRemote {
    /* custom methods */
}
```

If a class extends an exotic object that has restrictions on `this` context (see [the example with native `sessionStorage` object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339476/sessionstorage-proxy-class-scope/46340535#46340535)), or object methods were bound, wrapper methods should be provided for original methods any way. If wrapper methods are created programmatically (by iterating over properties with `for..in`, etc) and not through `class` syntax, merged declaration should be additionally used for proper typing.

Comment: Thanks, this "*TypeScript class should be augmented with an interface. This results in merged declaration that asserts that Remote methods are implemented*" is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: I had a library with a factory and a lot of dependencies and I could nicely extend the instance without touching vendor code. Such a nice thing in a good answer!

Comment: ...but I get that error: `Cannot assign to read only property 'prototype' of function 'class BaseRemote {` (with strict mode)

Comment: @DanielW. Reassignment of class proto indeed may not work depending on a setup. See the update, I expect it to be more universal.