# TypeScript data object class with Object.assign() properties from constructor argument

Tags: typescript

Here's a class that is constructed to augment a data object with methods.

```
export default class ViewModel<T> {
  constructor(props: T) {
    Object.assign(this, props);
  }

  foo() {
    console.log('This class and children have methods as well as data');
  }
}
```

Is it possible to have TypeScript understand that all the props of `T` exist on the instances of `ViewModel<T>`?

```
type User = { id: number; name: string };

const m = new ViewModel<User>({ id: 1, name: 'Alice' });

m.foo(); // fine

console.log(m.id); // Property 'id' does not exist
```

([Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=6#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28DGnUDOBcAagJbADuAshEpgDwAqAfHAN4BQccOEAdgRhR0OGNAAUYKBDAEAXHCYBKDtx5wA8gCMAVsDEA6QgTIBzfhJgALMgQA0cabILKA3OoC%20ndcggQJVS4NXgECCExgQ0wIMwkAciZbYjwTOFR%20BF5bTAQoYH44a1QAN2A4AFtgGzpiQjhKYExMdOIEVBhUePcvTm9OGABPMHKAVQJgKDgAXg44MgRFfnQK7Um3OH5UKsUhKDJ%20MzhPD04%20QXgKmc2qUgoaOiaGccmWCXZ5xbgARkctnbg8QAgpgyDhgPFjj1OBVDH4Au44AB6JFwZAHYA%20c7hSLRWISWELREouAABRkI1gg0BC0hCAgwGI-Ag8FAdhgnCAA))

If not, is there a better way to wrap a plain JS object with methods that access its data properties? I'm not attached to this abstract class and would be fine with `UserViewModel` in the above case, but the codebase already has many different `T` types and I'd prefer to re-use them if possible. (E.g. make `UserViewModel` reference `User` instead of duplicating much of that type's definition.)

I know I can also export an interface along with the class, like in [Extending `this` in Typescript class by Object.assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495665/extending-this-in-typescript-class-by-object-assign) , but I'd also like the methods in the class to know what values are available on `this`.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't allow the view model to have `props`? That makes the solution as simple as `m.props.id`.

Comment: This is a pre-existing design so that would require a large refactoring of existing code. Though additionally, from a design standpoint it's undesirable to require `.props` everywhere to hack around the type system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript really doesn't like to let you use `class` if the type you are extending or implementing doesn't have statically-known members.  A generic type like `T` doesn't work:

```
class Foo<T> implements T {} // error! 
// A class can only implement an object type or intersection of 
// object types with statically known members.
```

Typescript can *represent* such class constructors in the type system:

```
type BarConstructor = new <T>(props: T) => T & { foo(): void }; // okay
```

and if you had an object of that type you could use it the way you want to use `ViewModel`:

```
function makeABarAndDoThings(Bar: BarConstructor) {
  const bar = new Bar({ a: 1, b: "2", c: true });
  bar.foo(); // okay
  bar.a; // okay
  bar.b; // okay
  bar.c; // okay
}
```

but you can't use `class` to build a constructor that the compiler understands to be of that sort of generic type.

---

Note that when you write `class Foo {}`, you are introducing both a named *type* called `Foo`, corresponding to an instance of the class, and a named *value* called `Foo`, the constructor of the class.

Since we can't use your `ViewModel` class implementation directly, we will rename it out of the way, and then use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) and [type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases) to create a type and a value named `ViewModel` which does behave as you desire.

Here's the renamed class:

```
class _ViewModel<T> {
  constructor(props: T) {
    Object.assign(this, props);
  }
  foo() {
    console.log("This class and children have methods as well as data");
  }
}
```

And here are the new type-and-value combo:

```
type ViewModel<T> = _ViewModel<T> & T;
const ViewModel = _ViewModel as new <T>(props: T) => ViewModel<T>;
```

The type `ViewModel<T>` is defined as the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of your `_ViewModel<T>` with `T` itself.  And the new `ViewModel` value is the same as `_ViewModel` at runtime, but at compile time we've asserted that it is a generic constructor which takes a parameter of type `T` and produces a `ViewModel<T>`.

---

Let's see how it works:

```
type User = { id: number; name: string };

const m = new ViewModel<User>({ id: 1, name: "Alice" });

m.foo(); // fine
console.log(m.id); // also fine
```

Looks good to me now.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAfNAlgWwA4gFNsCA7AFxhWgG8BfaAegegICdX5WBCAKCegCC0UJBjAwJaPBIgAnljyFi5aBKkAjAFYFgZaGVm4CU1lnJsIOspmlSAZn2bwtV-YYIwA7pjIALaBBkYNbiIHLQANYk8J6SxNjqFgB0PDwGRtAAQmCsAMLSgawArrqc0AC80CQEntCoaAAUuBy4EABc0CgAlBUYVABkNNB2iA1dHQBu8JgAJtC0ANyMThFgsjx2RSS6NnFgEQQC2awCJDMAIvAovpgkAOYQDccdx-kkhSVknD3UPNDCBT06hyFSqNSyOQa1FUHQAjAAaaDqDoAIgATCjEcAOmRisZaF0Fn8kTkkiN4GMlvx4Kt1v9gawkmAqSs1sSGUl1CypLT2aTgNyaWzaKkRFBoAB9ABqmBqAFl4DMCCB6jRicBAcVSqwmi12p0fsT-gB5Fy6JlQTB3EgNPyYCCI5rwVqE4ki-7ksZq-7-DXveCEJIgeB3Boo6724TgcUSObAG4gGasUjQXxgCbGYh+RUwSDQTzKkCqGAzYJgFGu-4ikXpYwy+WK5WqyrS2WeBVKlXoaCDFBEv2BaD19uNost4cd5XFsG1eq65367q9IdtyddtBEtLuaAAVUspkq0NmHRIRQSbCWJDAxA6hVud3mm4HemwoOqtQno6Qe7YjSPMzhRErxvaAUQEEBMGAAgUXmV0eGwMlRkJZZhluAgeAHAMCCDEMGgQ2ZkP4MAQAgeBUOqHggA)