# Extending an instance (prototype) in TypeScript with strict mode enabled

Tags: node.js, typescript, extends, strict

I have an instance `remote` from a factory in a vendor script and I need to extend that instance with my own methods and members.

I found the following useful answer [Extending `this` in Typescript class by Object.assign](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48496131/1948292) suggesting

```
BaseRemote.prototype = remote;
```

It seemed a clean solution at first but, I suspect due to strict mode, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'prototype' of function 'class BaseRemote { }'
```

How can I extend an instance / change its prototype like that without disabling strict mode?

Comment: try Object.setPrototypeOf()

Comment: @captain-yossarian thanks captain it's working superb, please kindly post a short answer, best containing a link to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next example :

```js
Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, prototype)
```

Please see the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)

**UPDATE**
I think it worth looking on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495665/extending-this-in-typescript-class-by-object-assign) also